# How to make php IF statement between Javascript variable and php value on page load without submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have to get Browser Local date and time with Javascript and compare it in PHP IF statement with value from database on page load to determine if product expired or not. How do I solve the issue without using cookies and or sessions?

Javascript

```
 <script> 

      var currentDate = new Date(),
      day = ('0' + (currentDate.getDate()+1)).slice(-2),
      month = ('0' + (currentDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
      year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      var currentTime = new Date(),
      hours = currentTime.getHours(),
      minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

    if (minutes < 10) {
     minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }   

 document.write(day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes)

</script>
```

PHP

```
    if(strtotime( date and time from SCRIPT ) < strtotime($events date and time exiptation as $events_total_SKU[$e]['sales_end'])) 
{   
   print(" OK ");
 .... and  shopping cart code
}
     else{
   print(" Expired ");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: Why do you need this to be based on my local time to begin with? If I see that the product I want just “expired” minutes ago for me in my time zone, then what is supposed to stop me from simply changing the time zone on my system, to get access to your product again …?

Comment: Hi 04FS you perfectly right but the product is a Events tickets and pre-sales end at certain time and date. The site operates internationally and I need to close the sale on Event local time not on server time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should store both the dates in `JavaScript` variables as below. And compare it in Js as well.

```
  var currentDate = new Date(),
  day = ('0' + (currentDate.getDate()+1)).slice(-2),
  month = ('0' + (currentDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
  year = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var currentTime = new Date(),
  hours = currentTime.getHours(),
  minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();


  var frontendDate = year + '-' + month + '-' +day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes;


  var backednDateString = "<?php echo $events_total_SKU[$e]['sales_end'];?>";
  // As backedn date is string convert it as date first.
  var backednDateS  = new Date(backednDateString );

if(frontendDate  < backednDate) 
{   
   alert(" OK ");
}
else{
   alert(" Expired ");
}
```

Make sure format of both the dates are same.

Comment: Hi Rahat thanks al lot for quick answer. Problem is I have inside PHP  IF statement a whole lot of code to be executed if sale not expired instead of just an alert. I edited the PHP code accordingly